# minizip-asm returns an empty zip file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I can't find my mistake. It worked a few month ago. But now it returns an empty zip file. Also, it is not password secured. The name of the generated zip file is correct. Happy for some help.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var Minizip = require('minizip-asm.js'); 
        
var text = new Buffer.from("Abc~~~");
var mz = new Minizip();
                    
mz.append("../data/mysqlDump.sql", text, {password: '1111'});

let zipfile= "../data/mysqlDump.zip";

fs.writeFileSync(zipfile, new Buffer.from(mz.zip()));
```

EDIT:

I am using now node.js **jszip**. It works fine. But is there a simple way to protect a zipfile with a password? Because this feature is not included with jszip. I have a linux platform. Is there a way to protect a zip file with a password?